# How to set text for dropdownlist Combobox MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

when I change the combobox format from dropdown to dropdownlist, the SetWindowTextW method no longer seems to work?

How can I assign text to it in OnInitDialog event?

```
CComboBox m_dropdownlist;
```

whether there is a method as: **m_dropdownlist.setindex[0]**

[my dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4kq.png)

[my desire result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lsMo.png)

Comment: See CComboBox::SetCurSel(int index) which once you set the selection, changes the text in the "edit" box.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you very much! my question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you can use [`CComboBox::SetCurSel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class?view=vs-2019#setcursel).

It might be worth just taking a moment to think about when you map a combo to a variable. You basically have three ways:

1. You can map to a **control** variable (a `CComboBox`).
2. You can map to a **value** variable of type `CString` (when the combo is a drop down).
3. You can map to a **value** variable of type `int` (when the combo is a drop down list).

This is why it is acceptable to use `SetCurSel` because that is what the value variable would be holding - the current selected index.